# Calling a js file within a microstrategy report

Tags: javascript, microstrategy

i need to call javascript code from a js file to **add a dynamic url to a link** within my report, i've tried to use a html container to do just this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/sharedPage.js" ></script>
<script>

</script>
```

But until now i haven't had any success, when i try to call a function from the js file i just get a pop up saying that the function doesnt exist and as a result part of my report doesn't load, can anyone help thanks.

Comment: is the js allways the same? do you want to add this to a report or to a document? how do you call the function?

Comment: the js file is always the same and i want to add to a document, i tryed to use the html container and the microstrategy sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a simple SDK customization. You can find the steps to follow here:

http://community.microstrategy.com/t5/SDK/TN221321-How-to-Add-Custom-JavaScript-to-MicroStrategy-Web-Pages/ta-p/221321

The only difference, instead of selection the `desktop` page use the one for the documents.